# Using different symbols for plotting data not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am attempting to use a different symbol for one of my data series on my flot graph as it is at a much larger scale then the rest of the data. I am using this example as reference: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/symbols/index.html

Here is what I have so far:

My includes:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>
```

I then configure my flot options like so:

```
var options = {
        grid: {hoverable : true},
        xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%H:%M", tickLength: 1},
        series: { points : { show: true } }
        };
```

I then actually plot the data:

```
 $.plot('#placeholder', [{
               data: my_data,
               lines: { show : true},
               points: { symbol: "square"},
               color: '#CB4B4B',
               label: 'My Data'
               }], options);
        }
```

However, `flot` is still graphing the points as the default circle. I get no error messages in firebug and I have even tried adding a logging message in the `jquery.flot.symbol.js` library itself to see if the "square" handler is even being called like so:

```
var handlers = {
            square: function (ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
                console.log("Square handler was called");
                // pi * r^2 = (2s)^2  =>  s = r * sqrt(pi)/2
                var size = radius * Math.sqrt(Math.PI) / 2;
                ctx.rect(x - size, y - size, size + size, size + size);
            },
```

I am getting no console messages so I am assuming the handler is not getting called correctly. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

Example of data I am trying to plot:

```
var d1 = [
[1364342400000, 208],
[1364346000000, 107],
[1364353200000, 42],
[1364371200000, 1680],
[1364360400000, 52],
[1364349600000, 67],
[1364385600000, 1118],
[1364367600000, 163],
[1364382000000, 1359],
[1364378400000, 1468],
[1364389200000, 1023],
[1364356800000, 63],
[1364374800000, 1601],
[1364392800000, 556],
[1364364000000, 84],
],
d2 = [
[1364342400000, 86],
[1364346000000, 42],
[1364353200000, 13],
[1364371200000, 458],
[1364360400000, 10],
[1364349600000, 22],
[1364385600000, 453],
[1364367600000, 45],
[1364382000000, 369],
[1364378400000, 379],
[1364389200000, 358],
[1364356800000, 17],
[1364374800000, 471],
[1364392800000, 147],
[1364364000000, 16],
],
d3 = [
[1364342400000, 7],
[1364346000000, 5],
[1364382000000, 11709],
[1364371200000, 58336],
[1364360400000, 1],
[1364349600000, 1],
[1364367600000, 2],
[1364389200000, 1191],
[1364378400000, 9085],
[1364385600000, 4688],
[1364374800000, 9386],
[1364392800000, 1140],
[1364364000000, 1],
];
```

I have also edited my `options` parameter and how the plot function is called:

```
var options = {
grid: {hoverable : true},
xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%H:%M", tickLength: 1}
}; 

 $.plot("#placeholder", [{
data: d1,
lines: { show : true },
points: { show: true},
color: '#EDC240',
label: "d1"
}, {
data: d2,
lines: { show : true },
points: { show : true},
color: '#AFD8F8',
label: "d2"
}, {
data: d3,
yaxis: 2,
lines: { show : true},
points: { show: true, symbol: "square"},
color: '#CB4B4B',
label: "d3"
}], options);
```

I am also sure that the `symbol` library is being included because I have added some logging itself to the library and that is showing up fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no issue with what you've done.  I made a quick working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/shLtU/1/

I would guess that you haven't included the symbol library (even though you say you have).

Or show your data, might somehow be an issue there (doubtful?).

This is the full `flot` code I ran to make a working example (plus including flot and the symbol library):

```
$.plot('#placeholder', [{
    data: [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 9]
    ],
    lines: {
        show: true
    },
    points: {
        show: true,
        symbol: "square"
    },
    color: '#CB4B4B',
    label: 'My Data'
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have edited my question to include more info, including the data I am trying to plot. I am perplexed as to why it is not working since my code is very similar to yours above.

Comment: Indeed.... Even with that added detail, it's still not clear what the issue is - http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/shLtU/2/  shows all your changes and it still seems fine...

Comment: I should of check what version of `flot` I was running. The version I was using was `0.6` and as soon as I upgraded to `0.7` the square symbols worked perfectly. Your answer led me down the right track. Thank you for your help!